# iPhone 4 camera opacity

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, camera

I was wondering if it is possible to set the opacity of the camera input? For example if I have layers underneath the camera I want to be shown through the camera layer..

I work with the camera like this:

```
- (void)addVideoPreviewLayer {
    [self setPreviewLayer:[[[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:[self captureSession]] autorelease]];
    [[self previewLayer] setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

}

- (void)addVideoInput {
    AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];   
    if (videoDevice) {
        NSError *error;
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoIn = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:&error];
        if (!error) {
            if ([[self captureSession] canAddInput:videoIn])
                [[self captureSession] addInput:videoIn];
            else
                NSLog(@"Couldn't add video input");     
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"Couldn't create video input");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create video capture device");
}
```

And fire it up by:

```
[self setCaptureManager:[[CaptureSessionManager alloc] init]];
[[self captureManager] addVideoInput];
[[self captureManager] addVideoPreviewLayer];
CGRect layerRect = [[[self view] layer] bounds];
[[[self captureManager] previewLayer] setBounds:layerRect];
[[[self captureManager] previewLayer] setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),
    CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];
[[[self view] layer] addSublayer:[[self captureManager] previewLayer]];
```

It is possible? And if yes, how can it be done?

Comment: could you accomplish the same effect by placing the other view on top of your camera view and setting its opacity to be partially transparent?

Comment: @Dancreek: No, I'm afraid not. I've also experimented by putting a transparent white overlay on top of everything. But, I'm not quite satisfied..

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking then. Please clarify.

Comment: @Harkonian: I want to know if it's possible to set the camera layer's opacity. Exactly like when you set a imageview layers opacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previewLayer isn't composited like ordinary CALayers, so it's not surprising that changing its opacity doesn't work.

What you can try to do is use this code (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1702/_index.html) to capture the input from the camera in real-time, convert it to a UIImage, and stick that image into a UIImageView. I've found that with a session setting of AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium, you should be able to update your UIImageView at 20-30 fps, which may be sufficient for what you are trying to accomplish.